# What is the difference between restricting URLs based on Roles in the following two ways in spring security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

First way:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/employees").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/employees/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/employees").hasRole("MANAGER")
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/employees").hasRole("MANAGER")
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/employees/**").hasRole("ADMIN");
 
    http.httpBasic();
 
    http.csrf().disable();
 
    return http.build();
}
```

Second way:

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(configurer -> 
            configurer.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/employees").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/employees/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/employees").hasRole("MANAGER")
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/employees").hasRole("MANAGER")
            .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/employees/**").hasRole("ADMIN"));
 
    http.httpBasic();
 
    http.csrf().disable();
 
    return http.build();
}
```

I was trying to restrict access to Rest APIs based on Roles using Spring Security.
I found there are two ways to do so. Both are working fine, but I want to know if there is a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second way, according to this [article](https://dev.to/noelopez/spring-security-lambda-dsl-1a4m#:%7E:text=It%20is%20a%20new%20approach,of%20lambda%20expresions%20is%20optional.):

> It is a new approach to configure web security in Spring projects using lambda expressions. One of the main benefits of it is to avoid chaining using the and() method. It also promotes cleaner coding style in my opinion.
> Of course, the chaining style is still valid and the use of lambda expressions is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are equivalent in functionality wise and doing the same thing. The first way you used is the traditional way of configuring security.

The second way introduced in spring security 5.

The benefit of using the lambda function to make your code concise and easy to read.

In your code lines are may not appear to be significantly more concise than the first way.

But let's take an example. You have a list of integers and you want only that numbers which are greater than 10 so how much you get it. One way is to use the if condition inside the for-loop and say if no is greater than 10 then save it in new list but same thing you can achieve in one line of code

```
public class MinImp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1,10,4,50,70);

        //Traditional way to achieve it
        for(int i=0; i<integers.size();i++){
            if(integers.get(i)>10){
                System.out.println("Integer is: "+integers.get(i));
            }
        }

        //Using Streams and lamba function, you can do it in one line of code.
        integers.stream().filter(a->a>10).collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I can not see how concise the second way is. Both ways have the same number of lines.

Comment: yes you are correct, in this code lines are may not appear to be significantly more concise than the first way. But let's take an example. You have a list of integers and you want only that numbers which are greater than 10 so how much you get it. One way is to use the if condition inside the for-loop and say if no is greater than 10 then save it in new list but same thing you can achieve in one line of code.

List<Integer> integers = Arrays.asList(1,10,4,50,70);

one line of code:
 integers.stream().filter(a->a>10).collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(System.out::println);